# Cannot compile sqlite in Nerves firmware

Tags: nerves-project

This question has come up a bit by many others in #nerves slack.

Essentially, you try to include sqlite in Nerves firmware (usually via `esqlite`) and it fails on `mix firmware` during compilation:

```
===> Compiling esqlite
===> Compiling /Users/someone/repos/my_firmware/deps/esqlite/c_src/esqlite3_nif.c
===> /Users/someone/my_firmware/deps/esqlite/c_src/esqlite3_nif.c:25:10: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
 #include "sqlite3.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

`sqlite3.h` is definitely in the `esqlite` project.

Is it possible to get sqlite working in Nerves?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm getting the same error when trying to compile esqlite with `mix deps.compile`.  The sqlite3.h exists on the local machine, pointed to in CFLAGS, and it exists in the c_src/sqlite3 directory in the package.